# how to deserelize xml and print to console?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

i have a code

```
            [XmlRoot("user_list")]
        public class UserList
        {
            public UserList() { Items = new List<User>(); }
            [XmlAttribute("user")]
            public List<User> Items{get; set; }
        }
        [XmlType("user")]
        public class User
        {
            [XmlAttribute("id")]
            public string Id{get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("name")]
            public string Name{get; set; }   

        }        

    class Program
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            Program o = new Program();
                o.Deser();
            List<User> p = new List<User>();

            foreach (User c in p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Id);
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
            }     
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
             public void Deser()
        {
                List<User> users;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("fileXML.xml"))
    {
         XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<User>),  
            new XmlRootAttribute("user_list"));
        users = (List<User>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader)
    }  
   }
 }
```

and there is no output and no errors in VS. What i doing wrong? and how i can see what list contain in debug mode?
I think may be some problems whith deserialization, but don't know what is.

don't blame me(

BTW test xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user_list>
  <user>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Joe</name>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>John</name>
  </user>
</user_list>
```

Comment: Your not returning users in your method

Comment: You don't return anything from `o.Deser()`.  You call it, then do `List<User> p = new List<User>();` and try to print out the contents of the empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 [XmlRoot("user_list")]
    public class UserList
    {
        public UserList() { }
        [XmlAttribute("user")]
        public List<User> Items { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlType("user")]
    public class User
    {
        // [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        // [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: when you are using `XmlAttribute`  your XML file looks:

`<user_list>
  <user id="1" name="Joe" />
  <user id="2" name="John" />
</user_list>`

Answer (score 0):

Change signature of your method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<User> Deser()
    { /* all your code */
           return users; }
```

And change your Main:

```
    static void Main()
    {
           var users = Deser();
           /* your foreach */
     }
```

Comment: thank you for coments, but it still doesn't work(
first - when i view details of users in Deser() - all is "null", but anyway when i add it manually there is no effect(